# How to update a plot by calling data from within the program?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am writing a programme which takes a circular membrane and models its evolution under certain forces. The programme is as follows (with the details of the evolution omitted)

```
import numpy as np 
import math 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xCoords = {"%s" % i: np.array([math.cos(2*math.pi*i/360),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=float) 
for i in range(0, 360)} #coordinates stored in arrays whose entries correspond to time evolution
yCoords = {"%s" % i: np.array([math.sin(2*math.pi*i/360),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=float) 
for i in range(0, 360)}

#fill out arrays using diff eq.

x = np.zeros((360,10), dtype = float)
y = np.zeros((360,10), dtype = float)

for i in range(0,360):
    for j in range(0,10):
        x[i][j] = xCoords["%s" % i][j]
        y[i][j] = yCoords["%s" % i][j]
```

If I want to now plot the evolution of the coordinates over time, how would I do that?

I tried to plot with the following.

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```

but it just outputs [image]

In particular, how do I get a plot of just `(x[i][j],y[i][j])` at time *j*?
I then tried

```
for j in range(0,62):
    for i in range(0,360):
        plt.plot(x[i][j],y[i][j])
        plt.show()
```

but that didn't work either as it didn't give a new 'circle' everytime.

Comment: Please also post your attempt at a solution and show why it has failed.
Guidelines for asking a question is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
h, = ax.plot([],[])
ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

for time_ind in range(0,10):
    h.set_data(x[:, time_ind], y[:, time_ind])
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply. The arrays `X` and `Y` are 1-dimensional, so I get an error when I use your method.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with the array is 1-D? In the example above X and Y are both 2-D arrays with dimension (360,10)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant is there a way to do it with 1-D arrays?